# my opencart website is not displaying images on on way back machine

Tags: image, opencart

My opencart website is not displaying images on way back machine of Alexa.com (How did

`www.aaa------aa.com`

look in the past?), I have checked multiple dates but images does not display anywhere.

My opencart images are also not getting crawled by google merchant center, it shows that it is because of the `robots.txt` but I have removed images from `robots.txt` file & still it shows same error.

My website is working fine otherwise and I am also getting orders but want to know if the above two issues are interrelated and what can be the best solution to this problem.

Thanks,

Gaurav

Comment: What about the admin section? Does the images get displayed in admin section?

Answer (score 0):

from what you are saying i think the problem with wayback machine is that you cache of images got cleared so ofcource most urls of images are dead, since opencart get 98% of images from cache after they get resized. So no problem there, i think this happens with every oencart setup that cached images are cleared from time to time, also in the same fashion please check images folder and sub-directories if you have any .htaccess limiting everything but local requests, also one last notice google usually takes from one day and up to update data regarding robots.txt and other data.

And if nothing works out try to specifically allow access to one directory with robots.txt

Hope i could help you.